# Google Maps potential quota abuse scenario

Tags: google-maps, client-side-attacks

Let say I have added a map on my website, how would I prevent a user from exhausting my quota by indefinitely refreshing page to use up my quota and therefore increase my bill?

I have tested this scenario by running a Selenium script and it seems like every refresh does count towards quota usage. Does it have a mitigation?